# SF story published in *Analog* or *Asimov's* (1980s–1990s) that was about practical uses of counter-gravity/anti-gravity in racing/cars

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I've already asked this in Reddit's r/tipofmytongue [[1](https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/i6dzzp/tomt_sf_story_published_in_analog_or_asimovs_that/)], r/science_fiction [[2](https://www.reddit.com/r/sciencefiction/comments/j92fry/identification_request_sf_story_published_in/)], and r/printSF [[3](https://www.reddit.com/r/printSF/comments/qi7o9r/identification_request_sf_story_published_in/)].

The story was likely a novelette or novella, not a short story and almost certainly not a novel.

I thought the story was likely published between October 1989 and October 1990 (which is when I thought I read it) in [*Analog*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/seriesgrid.cgi?9094) or [*Asimov's*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/seriesgrid.cgi?20321) (except that I've checked the ISFDb's lists (at the links) for all of those issues and can't find a likely title).  Also, user Yammerhant of Reddit's r/printSF checked their collection of 1980s/90s *Analogs* and did not find any likely candidates, though that does leave *Asimov's*.

So it's actually not likely, but besides *The Dragon*/*Dragon Magazine*, those were the only genre magazines to which I subscribed, so *F&SF* etc. are out.  However, I did read a few stories from *Absolute Magnitude* and *Aboriginal Science Fiction*, as my local SF club had subscriptions.

More details:

- the counter-gravity/anti-gravity was depicted as applied to/developed in/used in high-end race cars (think Formula One/Indy Car/NASCAR; which ended up being fusion powered—nuclear powered, at least), and the technology's effects in that industry.
- The counter-gravity/anti-gravity mechanism ended up being two sets of hoops internal to the vehicle: a set of large ones for lift, and a set of thinner and more numerous ones for fine control.
- The male protagonist (an engineer?) is in love triangle with a woman involved with the project (a race team executive?) and a male race car driver (a young hotshot?).

Comment: I think *Analog* would be more likely than *Asimov's* as the latter tended to be more realistic in its science.

Comment: I agree.  In addition I read Asimovs pretty thoroughly during that timeframe and don't recall this story

Comment: I don't recall any other details.  Is there anything else I can do to help?

Comment: Just checking in.

Comment: Still checking in occasionally.